# How to do scrollbar outside textarea?

Tags: html, css, textarea, scrollbar

Can anybody have to do scrollbar outside `<textarea>` ?

I found something like this http://jsfiddle.net/jlmyers42/8tptqt19/ but it doesnt work for teaxtarea.

The best will be using only css and html.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm not sure about what do you mean, do you need a textarea element with an scrollbar inside it?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, have a scroll bar outside of that particular element you could encapsulate it within a `div` like so.

```
<div style="overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; height: 100px">
   <textarea style="overflow-y:auto;" placeholder="Enter Notes here (optional)"></textarea>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ga0e66oz/
The scrollbar will appear when you need to scroll. Give it a try.

Comment: Yes, it works but when I put long text to textarea I cannot scroll it because the scrollbar is assigned to div.

Comment: Of course, here is link: http://jsfiddle.net/o4acm4bn/, put text inside textarea and see that this scroll of div doesnt scroll all the text inside textarea.

Comment: @AsiaSka I've provided an answer.