# Custom scrollbar outside textarea related to text

Tags: html, css, textarea, scrollbar

I'm trying to create a scrollbar outside a textarea related to the text in this way:

[image]

The most similar approach I've found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102545/how-to-do-scrollbar-outside-textarea) but at the end the outer scrollbar only scrolls the textarea and the inner one scrolls the text.